# minimum height insertion orders for a Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

So in class one of my exercises was to find the insertion orders that result in a binary search tree with a minimum height and maximum height. The numbers being inserted were [1,2,3,4]. The resulting answer was this:

[image: answer]

Figure 3.9:
[image: diagram 3.9]

However what I fail to understand is why the insertion orders 1324,1342,4213,4231 are not included as an insertion order resulting in a minimum height, as technically don't these result in a BST with a minimum height of 2 as well?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting that the text doesn't mention those four cases. They don't have the worst case height, but they aren't minimal either. There are two features that characterize a tree:

- the maximum depth from the root to any node
- the average depth from the root to any node

A tree like 1432 has maximum depth 3, and average depth `(0+1+2+3)/4 = 1.50`
A tree like 3124 has maximum depth 2, and average depth `(0+1+1+2)/4 = 1.00`
A tree like 1324 has maximum depth 2, but average depth `(0+1+2+2)/4 = 1.25`

The best possible tree has the **smallest average** as well as the **smallest maximum** depth. To put it another way, the best possible tree has every level (except for the last) completely filled.

For example, even though the two trees below have the same number of nodes, and the same maximum depth, the tree on the left is not a minimum height tree because it's missing a node at the third level (which means that the average depth will be greater than the tree on the right).

[image]